# Vector/matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix

Some definitions:

```
#define _count(total) for (int count = 0; count < total; count++)

#define _xyCount(x,y) \
    for (int xCount = 0; xCount < x; xCount++) \
        {for (int yCount = 0; yCount < y; yCount++){ 

#define _xy }}
```

I just use these to save time.  The `_xy` is used cause if I don't, VS will act weird. Now for the vector and matrix.  I've created a number of different kinds of vectors and matrices and I post these as the general form.

```
struct vector3
{
    double e[3];

    ///////////////////////////

    vector3 operator/(double d)
    {
        vector3 out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count] / d;
        }
        return out;
    }

    vector3 operator*(double d)
    {
        vector3 out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count] * d;
        }
        return out;
    }

    vector3 operator-(vector3 vec)
    {
        vector3 out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count] - vec.e[count];             
        }
        return out;
    }

    vector3 operator+(vector3 vec)
    {
        vector3 out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count] + vec.e[count];
        }
        return out;
    }

    double operator*(vector3 vec)
    {
        double out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out += e[count] * vec.e[count];
        }
        return out;
    }

    vector3 operator%(vector3 vec)///-cross product
    {
        vector3 out;

        out.e[0] = e[1] * vec.e[2] - e[2] * vec.e[1];
        out.e[1] = e[0] * vec.e[2] - e[2] * vec.e[0];
        out.e[2] = e[0] * vec.e[1] - e[1] * vec.e[0];

        return out;
    }

    ////////////////////////////

    vector3()
    {
        e[0] = e[1] = e[2] = 0;
    }
    ~vector3(){}
}; typedef vector3 v3_;
```

This is the 3 by 3 matrix:

```
struct matrix_3x3
{
    double e[3][3];

    ///----------------

    matrix_3x3 operator/(double d)
    {
        _xyCount(3,3)

            e[xCount][yCount] /= d;         

        _xy

    }

    ///----------------

    matrix_3x3 operator*(double d)
    {
        _xyCount(3,3)

            e[xCount][yCount] *= d;         

        _xy

    }

    ///----------------
    ///-?
    vector3 operator*(vector3 v)
    {

        vector3 out;

        _xyCount(3,3)

                out.e[xCount] += v.e[yCount] * e[xCount][yCount];

        _xy

        return out;

    }

    ///----------------

    matrix_2x2 minorAltB(int column, int row)
    {

        matrix_2x2 out; 

        ///----------------------------
        int x, y;
        x = y = 0;

        _xCount(2)
        {
            y = 0;

            if (xCount == column)
            {
                x = 1;
            }

            _yCount(2)
            {

                if (yCount == row)
                {
                    y = 1;
                }

                out.e[xCount][yCount] = (int)(e[xCount + x][yCount + y]);

            }

        }
        ///----------------------------


        return out;

    }

    matrix_2x2 minorAlt(int column, int row)
    {

        matrix_2x2 m;
        int x, y;
        x = y = 0;

        _xyCount(3,3)

            if (xCount != column)
            {

                y = 0;

                if (yCount != row)
                {

                    m.e[x][y] = (int)(e[xCount][yCount]);

                    y = 1;

                }

                x = 1;

            }

        _xy

    }

    matrix_2x2 minor(int column, int row)
    {

        matrix_2x2 out;

        double temp[4]; 

        int count;

        _xyCount(3,3)

            if (xCount != column)
            {
                if (yCount != row)
                {
                    temp[count] = e[xCount][yCount];
                    count++;
                }
            }



        _xy

        out.e[0][0] = (int)temp[0]; out.e[0][1] = (int)temp[1];
        out.e[1][1] = (int)temp[2]; out.e[1][1] = (int)temp[3];

    }

    double det()
    {
        return minor(0,0).value() - minor(1,0).value() + minor(2,0).value();
    }

    matrix_3x3 transpose()
    {
        matrix_3x3 out;

        _xyCount(3,3)

                out.e[xCount][yCount] = e[yCount][xCount];
        _xy
        return out;
    }

    bool invert()
    {
        double d = det();

        if (d == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            matrix_3x3 m, t, i;

            double sign = 1;

            _xyCount(3,3)

                    m.e[xCount][yCount] = minor(xCount,yCount).value() * sign;

                    sign *= -1;

            _xy

            t = m.transpose();

            i = t / d;

            *this = i;

            return true;
        }

    }

    ///-------------------

    matrix_3x3( double ax, double ay, double az,
                double bx, double by, double bz,
                double cx, double cy, double cz)
    {
        e[0][0] = ax; e[1][0] = ay; e[2][0] = az;
        e[0][1] = bx; e[1][1] = by; e[2][1] = bz;
        e[0][2] = cx; e[1][2] = cy; e[2][2] = cz;
    }

    matrix_3x3()
    {
        _xyCount(3,3)

                e[xCount][yCount] = 0;
        _xy
    }

    ~matrix_3x3()
    {

    }

}; typedef matrix_3x3 m33_;
```

I've created 3 functions to get minors but haven't decided which one to go with.

Here is the 3D point, ray and triangle:

```
///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\
///     point3                       }
///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/
struct point3 : public v3_
{
    ///-nothing yet

    double x()
    {
        return e[0];
    }

    double y()
    {
        return e[1];
    }

    double z()
    {
        return e[2];
    }

    ///------------------------------

    void x(double n)
    {
        e[0] = n;
    }

    void y(double n)
    {
        e[1] = n;
    }

    void z(double n)
    {
        e[2] = n;
    }

    ///------------------------------

    void xyz(double X, double Y, double Z)
    {
        e[0] = X; e[1] = Y; e[2] = Z;
    }

    ///------------------------------

    double abs()
    {
        return cSqrt(_sq(e[0]) + _sq(e[1]) + _sq(e[2]));
    }

    double getDistance(point3 from)
    {
        point3 diff;

        diff.x(x() - from.x());
        diff.y(y() - from.y());
        diff.z(z() - from.z());

        return diff.abs();

    }

    ///------------------------------

    void operator=(vector3 v)
    {
        x(v.e[0]); y(v.e[1]); z(v.e[2]);
    }

    point3 operator+(point3 p)
    {
        point3 out;
        out.e[0] = e[0] + p.e[0]; 
        out.e[1] = e[1] + p.e[1]; 
        out.e[2] = e[2] + p.e[2];
        return out;
    }

    point3 operator-(point3 p)
    {
        point3 out;
        out.e[0] = e[0] - p.e[0]; 
        out.e[1] = e[1] - p.e[1]; 
        out.e[2] = e[2] - p.e[2]; 
        return out;
    }

    point3 operator/(double d)
    {
        point3 out;
        out.e[0] = e[0] / d; 
        out.e[1] = e[1] / d; 
        out.e[2] = e[2] / d;
        return out;
    }

    point3 operator*(double d)
    {
        point3 out;
        out.e[0] = e[0] * d; 
        out.e[1] = e[1] * d; 
        out.e[2] = e[2] * d;
        return out;
    }

    double operator*(point3 p)
    {
        double out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out += e[count] * p.e[count];
        }
        return out;
    }

    point3 operator%(point3 p)
    {
        point3 out;

        out.e[0] = e[1] * p.e[2] - e[2] * p.e[1];
        out.e[1] = e[0] * p.e[2] - e[2] * p.e[0];
        out.e[2] = e[0] * p.e[1] - e[1] * p.e[0];

        return out;
    }

    ///------------------------------

    point3(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        e[0] = a; e[1] = b; e[2] = c;
    }

    point3(){}
    ~point3(){}
}; 
typedef point3 p3_;

point3 origin3(0,0,0);
///||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\
///     ray                          }
///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/
struct ray : public m32_
{

    ///-----------------------------

    p3_ A()
    {
        p3_ out;
        out.x(e[0][0]); out.y(e[1][0]); out.z(e[2][0]);
        return out;
    }

    p3_ B()
    {
        p3_ out;
        out.x(e[1][0]); out.y(e[1][0]); out.z(e[2][1]);
        return out;
    }

    void A(p3_ a)
    {
        e[0][0] = a.x(); e[1][0] = a.y(); e[2][0] = a.z();
    }

    void B(p3_ a)
    {
        e[0][1] = a.x(); e[1][1] = a.y(); e[2][1] = a.z();
    }

    void AB(p3_ a, p3_ b)
    {
        A(a); B(b);
    }

    ///-----------------------------

    p3_ B_A()
    {
        p3_ out;
        out = B() - A();
        return out;
    }

    double length()
    {
        return B_A().abs();
    }

    ray getUnit()
    {
        ray out;

        out.B(A() + (B_A() / length()));

        return out;
    }

    p3_ getUV()
    {
        return getUnit().B_A();

    }

    ///-----------------------------

    ray(p3_ a, p3_ b)
    {
        A(a); B(b);
    }
    ray(){}
    ~ray(){}

};
///||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\
///     triangle3                    }
///+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/
struct triangle3 : public m33_
{
    Uint32 color;

    ///-------------------------------

    p3_ A()
    {
        p3_ out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count][0];             
        }
        return out;
    }

    p3_ B()
    {
        p3_ out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count][1];             
        }
        return out;
    }

    p3_ C()
    {
        p3_ out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count][2];             
        }
        return out;
    }

    ///-------------------------------

    void A(p3_ in)
    {
        _count(3)
        {
            e[count][0] = in.e[count];
        }
    }

    void B(p3_ in)
    {
        _count(3)
        {
            e[count][1] = in.e[count];
        }
    }

    void C(p3_ in)
    {
        _count(3)
        {
            e[count][2] = in.e[count];
        }
    }   

    ///-------------------------------

    p3_ P(int p)
    {
        p3_ out;
        _count(3)
        {
            out.e[count] = e[count][p];             
        }
        return out;
    }

    void P(int p, p3_ in)
    {
        if (p >= 3)
        {
            ///-do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            _count(3)
            {
                e[count][p] = in.e[count];
            }
        }
    }

    ///-------------------------------
    ///-find the angle at vertex A
    double ang()
    {
        ///-two vectors 'lines' on either side of vertex A
        p3_ b, c;

        ///-subtract A from each vertex to get required vectors
        c = B() - A();
        b = C() - A();

        ///-get the dot product 'dp'
        double dp = b * c;

        ///-get the lengths of each line
        double bAbs = b.abs();
        double cAbs = c.abs();

        ///-out set at 1000 for error check
        double out = 1000;

        ///-dbz check
        if (bAbs != 0 && cAbs != 0)
        {
            ///- b * c = bc(Cos(A))
            out = acos(dp / (bAbs * cAbs));
        }

        return out;

    }

    ///-find the angle at any vertex
    double ang(int p)
    {
        int i;

        double out = 1000;

        p3_ temp[2];

        _count(3)
        {

            if (count != p)
            {
                temp[i] = P(count); 
                i++;
            }

        }

        _count(2)
        {
            temp[count] = temp[count] - P(p);
        }

        double dp = temp[0] * temp[1];
        double absB = temp[0].abs();
        double absC = temp[0].abs();

        if (absB != 0 && absC != 0)
        {
            out = acos(dp / (absB * absC));
        }

        return out;

    }

    ///-------------------------------

    ///-find the center of the triangle
    p3_ center()
    {
        p3_ out;

        double X, Y, Z;

        _count(3)
        {
            X += e[0][count];
            Y += e[1][count];
            Z += e[2][count];
        }

        out = out / 3;

        return out;


    }

    p3_ normalAlt(int v = 0, bool added = false)
    {
        p3_ out;

        p3_ *others;

        _count(3)
        {
            if (count != v)
            {
                *others = P(count);
                others++;
            }
        }

        if (added)
        {
            out = P(v) + ((others[0] - P(v)) % (others[1] - P(v)));
        }
        else
        {
            out = (others[0] - P(v)) % (others[1] - P(v));
        }
        return out;
    }

    p3_ normal()
    {

        return (B() - A()) % (C() - A());

    }

    p3_ bounce(p3_ in, int vertex = 0)
    {
        p3_ out;

        out = in;

        p3_ left, forward;

        p3_ n = normal();

        p3_ diff;

        if (vertex > 2 || vertex < 0)
        {
            return in;
        }

        diff = in - P(vertex);

        left = diff % n;

        forward = left % n;

        ray u(in, in + forward); 

        u = u.getUnit();

        p3_ in_A = in - A();

        double den = in_A.abs() * n.abs();

        if (den == 0)
        {
            return in;
        }

        out = in + in_A * 2 * (cSqrt(1 - (_sq((in_A % n) / den))));

        return out;
    }

    triangle3 reflect(p3_ pov)
    {
        triangle3 out;

        _count(3)
        {
            out.P(count,bounce(pov,count));
        }

        return out;
    }

    ///-------------------------------

    double getDistance(p3_ p)
    {
        double out;

        ray r;

        r.AB(p, A());

        out = r.length();

        r.B(B());

        if(out > r.length())
            out = r.length();

        r.B(C());

        if(out > r.length())
            out = r.length();

        return out;
    }

    ///-------------------------------

    triangle3(p3_ a, p3_ b, p3_ c)
    {
        A(a); B(b); C(c);
    }

    triangle3()
    {
        color = WHITE;
    }
    ~triangle3(){}

};
typedef triangle3 t3_;
///||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I've actually used this to raytrace successfully and render a reflected circular light onto a polygon.  Unfortunately, it took almost ten seconds to render so I must be doing something wrong.  If there's a good matrix/vector library out there I might use someone else's code.  If this is the best I can get, I want to figure out how to make a matrix of varying dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

A few aesthetic points worth mentioning:

- I find those `_count` and `_xy` macros to be a terrible idea. They greatly obfuscate the code and are very fragile constructs. It is very easy to break them. Just use plain `for` loops. It will be a lot more straightforward.
- Names stating with an underscore, in the global namespace, are a bad idea. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654).
- An empty destructor is pointless. Omit the destructor if the class doesn't require special cleanup.
- Apparently pointless typedefs? Why did you typedef `vector3` to `v3_` and `matrix_3x3` to `m3_`? That seems like just more code obfuscation that hurts readability.
- There are consecutive blank lines in some places. This makes your code look untidy.
- A suggestion on naming convention: `PascalCase` is more popular for type names, while `camelCase` is frequently used for method and variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I remember hearing about the dangers of leading underscores a while back.  Now I'll remember not to use them.  Are empty constructor's just as pointless?  I use v3_ and m33_ just to save space.  If I write a function with lots of arguments, my ocd acts up when it wraps to the next line.  And I use the blanks just to keep separate things more clearly separated.  It's easier for me to read.  When you say type names, you mean class names, right?

Comment: @Mindril - Yes, an empty constructor is also unnecessary. My problem with the two names for the same thing is that it can be a source of confusion. Some might think `vector3` and `v3_` are different things. Why not make a compromise and replace both with `Vec3` perhaps? No problem with spacing the code well, but avoid multiple consecutive blank lines. Those look unnatural. By type names I mean class, struct, typedef, and such.

Comment: Empty constructors are actually slightly different to an undefined constructor. As the compiler will generate two versions of a default constructor (one is used for value initialization the other being used for zero initialization). If your class contains any POD members (or has a member or inherits from a class with POD members and a compiler generated constructor) then the only safe thing to do is have a constructor that specifically initializes POD members (this includes arrays of integers).

Comment: Yes, indeed, very well noted @LokiAstari.

Answer (score 0):

I'm toying around with this idea:

```
template <typename type>
class matrix_AxB
{
    unsigned int rows, columns;

public:

    type *e;

    matrix_AxB(unsigned int r, unsigned int c)
    {
        rows = r; columns = c;
        e = new type[rows][columns];
    }
    ~matrix_AxB()
    {
        delete e;
    }

};
```

to replace all the matrices and vectors I've so far created.  The difficult part will be in learning how to generalize the dot and cross products for varying dimensions.

Comment: Do you really need varying dimensions? Usually, for 3D rendering and such, you only need 3D vectors and 4x4 homogeneous matrices...

Comment: Also, [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) is a very popular 3D maths library.

Comment: I just thought the AxB would cut down on code but if this all proves to be too challenging, then I may go with GLM.  I'm surprised how much their code looks like mine.  There's is probably way better though.

Comment: Can I make a point or polygon class that inherits from an AxB with specified dimensions?  Or can they only inherit from the general form?

Comment: Varying size might promote some code reuse, but will stop you from applying several useful optimizations and will probably make the whole thing a lot more complicated. If you really plan on using variable sizes, then I would suggest making the class a template with `A`x`B` sizes as template arguments. You still have to define the size at compile time, but the code reuse is possible.

Comment: @glampert What do you mean when you say my for macros are easily broken?  Do you mean I'll forget I'm inside the loop or the compiler will mistreat it?

Comment: Macros can be a big source of headache. They don't respect scope, can be silently redefined, produce poor error messages and the list goes on. You should always prefer a more modern solution over a macro if there is a choice. I didn't mean that yours **are** broken but that it is very easy to break code using them. One class of error, like you've noted, would be not knowing the `_xyCount` is in fact producing a loop.